# Wireless connection: Link Quality: What does "31/70" indicate?

Tags: wireless-router, wireless-access-point, antenna

I know that the link quality indicates the packet drops, errors etc. But when it tells me that link quality is "31/70", what is '31' and what is '70'?

Comment: Where did you read those values?

Comment: a vaguely intelligent guess would say 70 is a perfect score & you've less than half that. Units may be arbitrary.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WLAN Link quality: What does it mean?](http://superuser.com/questions/203231/wlan-link-quality-what-does-it-mean)

Comment: @Tom Wijsman Probably `iwconfig`. If you try something like: `iwconfig wlan0 | grep 'Link Quality'`, you should get something like: `Link Quality=46/70  Signal level=-64 dBm`.

Answer (score 16):

In [the code](https://git.openwrt.org/?p=project/iwinfo.git;a=blob;f=iwinfo_nl80211.c;hb=HEAD) for `iwinfo`, a newer tool similar to `iwconfig`, is a comment that states:

> /* The cfg80211 wext compat layer assumes a signal range of -110 dBm to -40 dBm, the quality value is derived by adding 110 to the signal level */

Adding 110 moves the minimum value to 0 to simplify the presentation of the range and thus moves the maximum to 70. To convert signal strength to a percentage [0,100], do:

```
quality_percent = (signal_strength + 110) * 10 / 7
```

In one of the functions, the quality value is stored in a variable named `rssi` which is an acronym for [received signal strength indication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Received_signal_strength_indication), "an indication of the power level (signal strength in arbitrary units) being received by the receive radio after the antenna and possible cable loss."

Speaking of "wext" (in the aforementioned code's comment) and `iwconfig`, in 2015, Wireless-Extensions (WE or Wext) and its tools including `iwconfig` were [abandoned](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/developers/Documentation/Wireless-Extensions) by the Linux kernel wireless developers. Its replacements are [cfg80211](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/developers/documentation/cfg80211) and [nl80211](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/developers/documentation/nl80211), and the tool [they strongly recommend](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/documentation/iw) is `iw`.